# Read only recent sms in android

Tags: android, sms

i am developing one application that is receiving sms from inbox ,i am receiving sms successfully but my requirement is receive only new(recent)message ,i do not want to read all messages from inbox ,please help me

my Code is

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    TextView showText;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    showText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
    String message = getMessagess();

    showText.setText(message);
}

public String getMessagess(){
    Cursor cursor=null;
    Uri smsuri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
    try{
     cursor =getContentResolver().query(smsuri, null, null, null, null);
     if (cursor == null) {
         // Log.i(TAG, "cursor is null. uri: " + mSmsQueryUri);

      }

     for(boolean   
         hashdata=cursor.moveToFirst();hashdata;hashdata=cursor.moveToNext()){

        final String body =   
        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")).toString(); 
         final String senderNo= 
        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).toString();
         final String  date = 
      cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("date"));
         final String  type = 
      cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("type"));

     if(senderNo.equals("+XXXXXXXXXX")){

         for(String bd:body.split(";"))
         sb.append(bd);

         sb.append("\n");

         }
     }
    if(sb==null){

        sb.append("no message found");
    }

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
    cursor.close();
    }
    return sb.toString();       
}
```

}

Comment: do you want recent SMS from inbox or new SMS arrived in inbox.?

Comment: i want new SMS arrived in inbox

Comment: For that you need to create a BroadCastReceiver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that you need to create BroadcastReceiver which receive `SMS_RECEIVED` broadcast and send alert to your application that New SMS has been arrieved.

Try with following code.

**ReceiveSMSActivity  :**

```
public class ReceiveSMSActivity extends Activity {

public static TextView messageBox;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    messageBox=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.messageBox);
}

public static void updateMessageBox(String msg) {
    messageBox.append(msg);
}

}
```

**TextMessageReceiver :**

```
public class TextMessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle bundle=intent.getExtras();

    Object[] messages=(Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
    SmsMessage[] sms=new SmsMessage[messages.length];

    for(int n=0;n<messages.length;n++){
        sms[n]=SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) messages[n]);
    }

    for(SmsMessage msg:sms) {
        ReceiveSMSActivity.updateMessageBox("\nFrom: "+msg.getOriginatingAddress()+"\n"+
                "Message: "+msg.getMessageBody()+"\n");
    }
}
}
```

add this in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<receiver android:name=".TextMessageReceiver"> 
    <intent-filter> 
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> 
    </intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```

and this permission too

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

Another SampleCode : [How-to-receive-SMS](http://learnandroideasily.blogspot.nl/2012/11/how-to-receive-sms.html)